# Where do I find lyrics to "Opportunity for Progress", by Rayne?

Tags: lyrics

Well, this has been bugging me for quite a while, but I simply can't find the lyrics to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Ma9tDBYXr8) song. Can anyone help?

It would also be fine to simply upload the lyrics. I am able to understand almost 80-85%, but that 15%... man, it's impossible to make out the words

Comment: The lyrics don't appear to be available on the web. Could you provide the verse(s) that you are having difficulty with the time they occur in the audio/video. Highlight the problem areas with  "*"s.

Comment: @LittleVoice, *The lyrics don't appear to be available on the web*, that is exactly why I asked the question here ;) Also, I will post the phrases soon :)